# Adding styles to QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, styles, qwidget, qpushbutton

I have created a qpushbutton in the source file ".cpp":

```
QPushButton * btn = new QPushButton("Click me");
```

and now I want to add styles to it. Like changing the background, adding border-radius, changing the cursor, and so on.

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
btn->setObjectName("mybtn");
btn->setStyleSheet(QString(""
                         "#mybtn{background-color: #182848; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid transparent; color: white;}"
                         "#mybtn:hover{background-color: white; border-color: #182848; color: #182848;}"
                         ));
```